# Conditional formatting based on the difference between two cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have % Budget Remaining in Column G and % Program Period Remaining in Column H.  Sometimes column G is the larger number, and sometimes column H is the larger number.  I want to color code it based on the difference between columns G and H.

If the difference is less than 10% = Green

If the difference is 10-19.9% = Yellow

If the difference is 20% or greater = Red

I am wanting to do this for the entire column, excluding blanks. If that isn't possible, I will gladly enter it into each cell because it's a short spreadsheet. I know it will need to be at least 3 rules.  I have read many posts, but can't seem to figure it out because most are referring to a value in a cell, not a value calculated between cells, if that makes sense.  The closest I can get is this rule below, but it turns things green that aren't supposed to be green.  Help!!

=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(H1)),ABS(G1-H1)<10)

Comment: Are the % budgets provided in whole numbers or percentages in the data? Do you have sample data to provide to show the whole issue? I ask as you mention percentages but your formula is looking at `<10` as less than 1000% if the numbers they are comparing are in percentages.

Comment: In Excel, percentages are fractions, So `10%` = `0.1` and so on. try `=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(H1)),ABS(G1-H1)<0.1)`

Comment: Oh my gosh!  Thanks, you guys!!  I don't know why it didn't occur to me that it needs to be in decimal form.  That worked!

Comment: Feel free to delete question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these formulas:

If the difference is less than 10% = Green:

```
=ABS(G1-H1)<=0.1
```

If the difference is 10-19.9% = Yellow:

```
=AND(ABS(G1-H1)>0.1,ABS(G1-H1)<=19.9)
```

If the difference is 20% or greater = Red:

```
=ABS(G1-H1)>=0.2
```

[image]